# Merge servlet parameters from web.xml and container context

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, configuration

We build a webapp using ServletAPI 3 in combination with Tomcat 7 on RHEL.

I try to set a context specific init parameter [getServletConfig().getInitParameter("myinit");] via any of

- ${CATALINA_HOME}/server.xml (no conf-directory in between but obviuosly the same)
- {engine}/{host}/{app}.xml

and to provide some meaningfull default ressource values via webapps war file content "META-INF/context.xml" in parallel.

But as soon as I define a context definition in the XMLs the defined DB connection we provide by context.xml within the war is ignored.
We build the webapp with ant as a single {app}.war file.

Obviously I don't provide the right settings but I don't understand how to do that without moving the db connection settings from META-INF/cotext.xml to the containers context definition (we don't want to do that - though this may obviously be a viable alternative).

Is it possible at all? If so: How? Is there an alternative option to do something similar?

Thanks a lot in advance!